# In Ckeditor 4, how can I change font-size of body on the fly after the editor instance has been fully initialized?

Tags: ckeditor

As per title. In Ckeditor 3, editor.addCss() does the trick, but version 4 does not have the this method. Is there an easy way set custom css to the editor after its been fully initialized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

got the solution from the official api docs:

```
editor.document.getBody().setStyle(key, val)
```

or

```
editor.document.appendStyle()
```